# Slim PHP Problema com CORS

Tags: php, cors, slimframework

Estou tentando fazer um requisição no servidor porem estou com problema na configuração do `CORS`, a api foi desenvolvida com o framework Slim Php e estou utilizando o middleware [PSR-7 and PSR-15 CORS middleware](https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware) , deixei como padrão as configurações do middleware, adicionando apenas `ignoreloadingbar` por conta de um bug de componente do angular, não sei se configurei corretamente o `side-server`:

Request:

```
Host: zooflora
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,ignoreloadingbar
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Jul 2018 15:41:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=p04ghhja7tp7jisk9fknrr1p9j; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, authorization,
accept, ignoreloadingbar, x-requested-with,multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Apesar de constar `status 200 Ok` eu recebeo a mensagem:

> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

e no Google Chrome:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Aplicação: http://localhost:4200 
Api: http://zooflora

Obs: No Google chrome quando eu adiciono a linha: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` no `.htaccess` eu consigo realizar as requisições normalmente, **porem não funciona no firefox**, eu uso um `addons` no mozilla para desabilitar o `CORS` dessa forma tudo funciona corretamente, mas preciso saber como configurar isso de forma correta.

vocês conseguem visualizar aqui: https://previa.surpresapropaganda.com.br/login (só clicar em acessar e olhar o console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de 3 dias consegui resolver e configurar de forma correta:

no `.htaccess` essa linha ainda é necessária para funcionar no Google Chrome, no Mozilla não faz diferença, eu acredito que ele ignora:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

e a configuração no `Middleware` ficou assim:

```
$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware([
    "origin" => ["http://dominio.com.br"],
    "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],    
    "headers.allow" => ["Origin", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Accept", "ignoreLoadingBar", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    "headers.expose" => [],
    "credentials" => true,
    "cache" => 0,        
]));
```

só precisei adicionar o metodo `OPTIONS` e remover alguns `HEADRERS ALLOWS` inválidos. agora tudo esta funcionando corretamente.

consegui entender melhor meu problema lendo esse doc [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header)